# Is there a way to tell how much code from some point in time still exists in a Git repo?

Tags: git

I would like to be able to see how much code present at a certain commit still exists in the repo as of a later commit. Even an approximation would be useful (e.g. 45% of lines present at commit X are still present at commit Y).

I'm would think this is doable in some fashion, but is it doable in a reasonable and scriptable way?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could diff the two points and check how many lines have been *deleted* so that you can have an idea how how much code *remains* from the original revision. `git diff --shortstat` might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

The `--stat` option of `git diff` gives the files and the amount of changes between two commits:

`git diff --stat <commit-hash> <commit-hash>`

The output can look like this:

```
$ git diff --stat HEAD^ HEAD
_start/index.html |    1 -
_scss/_variables.scss |    2 +-
_scss/head.scss       |   42 +++++++++++++++---------------------------
3 files changed, 16 insertions(+), 29 deletions(-)
```